# Querying SQL table with different values in same column with same ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, sql-server-2012, querying

I have an SQL Server 2012 table with `ID, First Name` and `Last name`. The `ID` is unique per person but due to an error in the historical feed, different people were assigned the same id.

```
------------------------------
    ID  FirstName   LastName
------------------------------    
    1    ABC         M
    1    ABC         M
    1    ABC         M
    1    ABC         N
    2    BCD         S
    3    CDE         T
    4    DEF         T
    4    DEG         T
```

In this case, the people with `ID’s` 1 are different (their last name is clearly different) but they have the same `ID`. How do I query and get the result? The table in this case has millions of rows. If it was a smaller table, I would probably have queried all `ID’s` with a `count > 1` and filtered them in an excel.

What I am trying to do is, get a list of all such `ID's` which have been assigned to two different users.

Any ideas or help would be very appreciated.

Edit: I dont think I framed the question very well.

There are two ID's which are present multiple time. 1 and 4. The rows with id 4 are identical. I dont want this in my result. The rows with ID 1, although the first name is same, the last name is different for 1 row. I want only those ID's whose ID is same but one of the first or last names is different.

I tried loading ID's which have multiple occurrences into a temp table and tried to compare it against the parent table albeit unsuccessfully. Any other ideas that I can try and implement?

Comment: What is the result that you want to get?

Comment: I am sorry. I wasn't very clear. Just edited the question.

Comment: After re-read your question, I am even more confused. You said "the rows with id 4 are identical". Compared to the data you gave, this is not true (`DEF <> DEG`).

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
    ID
FROM
    <<Table>>
GROUP BY
    ID
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for your time but I was looking for something different. I realized my question is not complete. So, I just updated it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE ID IN (
      SELECT ID
      FROM myTable
      GROUP BY ID
      HAVING MAX(LastName) <> MIN(LastName) OR MAX(FirstName) <> MIN(FirstName) 
      )
ORDER BY ID, LASTNAME
```

Comment: Thank you for your time but I was looking for something different. I realized my question is not complete. So, I just updated it :)